# Visual C++: How to See Included Files in Object Browser

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

This question is related to Visual Studio in general. In my case I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express.

When I include a file in a C++ project, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
```

the intellisense menu is automatically updated to list namespaces, members, methods, etc. defined in the file. But when I open the Object Browser, I only see my project and the definitions it contains, not those from the included file.

How can I see the definitions from included files in the Object Browser, like when referencing a COM or .NET library? Is this simply a limitation of the Express edition?

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  You'd have to copy the file to another directory and add it to the Header Files section to see its content in the browser.  This is not practical.  And you *really* don't want to see the horrid glue.